# Suggestions for a bad PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, popup

We have a legacy server service running on a Windows 7 desktop that keeps crashing with a popup window reporting a memory error. The popup stops all processing on the machine. Once the "OK" button is clicked on the popup the system recovers and moves on. The root problem appears to be inside a compiled DLL that the application uses.

- This popup usually happens between 9pm and 11pm every couple days.
- It happens when no one is signed into the PC, so the popup displays in front of the CTRL+ALT+Delete message for signing in.
- **I can click OK and it continues processing, signing into the computer**.

**CHALLENGE:**

- This is a legacy application that will be replaced when budget allows (maybe next Summer) so **there is no budget for upgrade or paying a consultant to fix the root problem**.
- All we need to do is click the OK button when the "Application Popup" event is thrown (logged in the Event Manager)

I know that it would be WRONG to write a script to satisfy the popup. Fixing the root cause is the CORRECT action.. but we have no support to spend money at this time. And since it's a compiled DLL, we can't fix the code.

**Is there a PowerShell script that could:**

- Watch for a specific event "Application Popup" and if it occurs simulate pressing the ENTER key?
- Run in the background, signed out of a user account.

**If PowerShell isn't the answer, is there a better macro or script tool to get us by?**
I know it's "bad practice" but we just need to get along until we get some budget dollars.

Comment: Does the problem occur if one is logged on the console and locked the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell probably isn't the best answer in this case. I'd suggest using something like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) (the [WinWaitActive](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinWaitActive.htm) function would be useful in your case).

I have used AutoIt in the past and have found it very useful for Windows GUI automation.